# Setting appropriate parameters for backups

Tags: backup, mirror

I need to make sure I am employing best practices while adhering to my company's requirements.
1. 7 days of data backups, that overwrite when the day repeats. I have the naming convention as DBNAME_DAYNAME.BAK. I achieved this with a cursor that dynamically builds the name.
2. Transaction log backups occur every minute and are named DBNAME_DAYNAME_MINUTEOFDAY.TRN. Similarly, these should overwrite when the 8 day starts in the cycle. Similar cursor is being used.
3. Copy data backups to network share. I am using CmdExec after each backup completes.
4. Copy log backups to network share. I am using Backup Log to Disk and Mirror to Disk.

I need to make sure my parameters are correct.

For the data file backups in step 1, I am using the following parameters:
WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION, STATS = 10

Then, I have a second step that copies the files to a network share:
Copy H:\BACKUPS\SQLDataFiles*.* """\192.xxx.xxx.xxx\sharepath\Directory*.*""" /Y

QUESTION 1: All of this appears to work. Are my parameters okay?

For the Log file backups, I am using Mirror to Disk, with the following parameters:
WITH FORMAT, INIT, SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION, STATS = 10

QUESTION 2: All of this appears to work, but are my parameters okay?

Of course, as it usually happens, the whole process was rushed by leadership, and I have not actually done a restore test. I will soon but wanted to get a review of the parameters by this wise group. The parameter descriptions are not sinking in. Admittedly, administration is not my forte. The parameters I am using are copied from other code, and some seem to imply tape. There is no tape, only disk. If they are tape and it does not cause problems, that is fine. I just want to make sure that the files are overwriting, and that I can recover with this setup.

Answer (score 0):

I can not tell you if the parameters are fine. What I could tell is that I would definitely prefer to use a real and reliable backup and restore software. Why is that:

- backup and restore tools are designed for that exact purpose
- backup and restore tools provide more features than the "naming" one, which actually reflects a *retention time* need: like beeing able to find the data to restore based on dates, search system and so on
- backup and restor tools can come with support contrat that give you an insurance to be helped if needed.

There are many backup and restore tools and as I am an open source guy I would suggest to go with Bacula (https://www.bacula.org) or the enterprise version of it (https://www.baculasystems.com) accordingly with your enterprise SLAs, policies or requirements.

Best regards

Werlan